# Idiomatic sync of concurrent activities ('map-reduce') in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

**EDIT**

Thanks to answers, I have a working version.  Code at end of question; thanks to @estus and @Jared for their help.

**Original Question**

Working my way into Node, and trying to get a handle on concurrency.  Starting with a simple example: given the name of two files, determine which is bigger.  Conventional (sequential) solution:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var fname1=process.argv[2]
var fname2=process.argv[3]

var stats1 = fs.statSync(fname1)
size1=stats1["size"]

var stats2 = fs.statSync(fname2)
size2=stats2["size"]

if(size1 > size2) {
    console.log(fname1 + " is bigger")
} else if (size2 > size1) {
    console.log(fname2 + " is bigger")
} else {
    console.log("The files are the same size")
}
```

Now suppose I want to stat the files in parallel*.  I can convert the code to use the async `stat` function:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var fname1=process.argv[2]
var fname2=process.argv[3]

fs.stat(fname1, function doneReading(err, stats) {
    size1=stats["size"]
    fs.stat(fname2, function doneReading(err, stats) {
        size2=stats["size"]
        if(size1 > size2) {
            console.log(fname1 + " is bigger")
        } else if (size2 > size1) {
            console.log(fname2 + " is bigger")
        } else {
            console.log("The files are the same size")
        }
    })
})
```

However:

1. It's less readable;
2. It won't scale well if I want to compare >2 files;
3. Not sure it would even stat the files in parallel (I'm unclear atm how the background threading works).

**So, to be specific, what's the idiomatic way to:**

1. Spawn multiple actions concurrently, then
2. Use their combined results once all are complete?

Perhaps promises might be a candidate?  `Promise.all` looks like the way to await all promises, but not clear how to actually use their results.

Thanks.

**SOLUTION**

```
'use strict';

const co = require('co');
const fs = require('fs-promise');

var fname1=process.argv[2]
var fname2=process.argv[3]

co(function* () {
    let res = yield [fs.stat(fname1), fs.stat(fname2)];
    let size1 = res[0]["size"]
    let size2 = res[1]["size"]
    if(size1 > size2) {
        console.log(fname1 + " is bigger")
    } else if (size2 > size1) {
        console.log(fname2 + " is bigger")
    } else {
        console.log("The files are the same size")
    }
})
```

It's very readable, succinct, and completely devoid of callback nastiness.  And readily extensible to comparing *n* files.

--

*Yes I know there's no need to do so for this scenario; the purpose is to understand the pattern using a simple example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fs.stat(fname1, function doneReading(err, stats) {
    ...
    fs.stat(fname2, function doneReading(err, stats) {
    ...
```

is still sequential and not parallel, the difference from `fs.statSync` is that it `fs.stat` is non-blocking.

The suggested 'readable' approach in modern Node are promises and `co`. `fs.stat` may be promisified (with `pify` or Bluebird's `Promise.promisify`/`Promise.promisifyAll`). Or some existing promisified `fs` package may be used, like `fs-promise`.

Sequential and non-blocking alternative to the code above may look like:

```
'use strict';

const co = require('co');
const fs = require('fs-promise');

co(function* () {
    let stat1 = yield fs.stat(fname1);
    let stat2 = yield fs.stat(fname2);
    ...
});
```

If we want to make it parallel, `Promise.all` steps in:

```
co(function* () {
    let [stat1, stat2] = yield [fs.stat(fname1), fs.stat(fname2)];
    // a shortcut for
    // let [stat1, stat2] = yield Promise.all([fs.stat(fname1), fs.stat(fname2)]);
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to estus's excellent answer, this may be a little easier to grok:

```
let stat = Promise.promisify(fs.stat.bind(fs));
Promise.all(arrOfPaths.map(stat)).then(arrOfResults => {
  // do stuff
});
```

As noted you will need to write the promisify function or use a library that adds it.

Here is an example implementation:

```
const promisify = fn => {
  return function(...args) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fn.apply(this, [...args, (err, ...rest) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        }
        let result;
        switch (rest.length) {
          case 0:
            result = true;
            break;
          case 1:
            result = rest[0];
            break;
          default:
            result = rest;
            break;
        }
        resolve(result);
      }]);
    });
  };
};
```